JavaFX sorted ObservableCollections with removals allowed
Look, I just want my ListView to be sorted and allow additions/removals.  I'm not the best at this, but this seems way harder than it should be.  If it matters, the data being stored is just a record that has some text to display in the ListView with some other text that is displayed in a separate box when selected in the ListView.
By default, the collection isn't sorted and doesn't allow removals.
I tried this:
tables = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
SortedList<TableData> sortedTables = new SortedList<>(tables);
sortedTables.setComparator(TableData.getComparator());
tableList = new ListView<>(sortedTables);

And I have
tables.remove(currentData);

which throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
I tried dropping the SortedList, but it didn't help.
I thought that the ArrayList version of Observable allowed removals, but apparently it doesn't.  Am I doing something stupid?  Maybe I could use an ObservableSet or ObservableMap somehow, but I don't understand why what I have doesn't work.

ObservableList has methods to add, remove, etc., methods. Also, there is a sorted method for sorting the items in the list.

Based solely on the code snippet you provided, you should not be getting that UnsupportedOperationException. Could you please create and provide a [mre]?

Why are you doing tableList = new ListView<>(sortedTables);? It seems odd to me.

The code you posted works just fine; if you are getting an exception it is because of other code that you have not included in the question.
The list returned by FXCollections.observableArrayList() implements all the optional operations in the List interface, including add(...) and remove(...).
On the other hand, a SortedList fulfills a contract that its elements are always in the order specified by the comparator. It is not possible to implement all the optional operations and still fulfill this contract. For example, the add(E element) method adds an element to the end of the list; if the element is not the last (as defined by the comparator) in the list, this would break the contract. Consequently, the SortedList simply implements all optional operations to throw an UnsupportedOperationException.
As long as you only try to modify the underlying list (the one returned by FXCollections.observableArrayList()), you will not get an UnsupportedOperationException. The code posted in the question does this, so will not throw an exception. If you are seeing an exception, it is probably because you are calling remove() on the SortedList. (Maybe you are reassigning the value of tables somewhere; or maybe you are not really calling tables.remove() but sortedTables.remove() or, equivalently, tableList.getItems().remove(). There is no way to know as you have not posted the code that is causing the problem.)
Here is a complete example that demonstrates that the code posted in the question works. Add tables by typing the name in the text field and pressing ENTER. Remove tables by selecting one in the list and pressing the remove button.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    record TableData(String name, String description) {
        static Comparator<TableData> getComparator() {
            return Comparator.comparing(TableData::name);
        }
    }

    private ListView<TableData> tableList;
    private ObservableList<TableData> tables;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Code copied from original post:
        tables = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        SortedList<TableData> sortedTables = new SortedList<>(tables);
        sortedTables.setComparator(TableData.getComparator());
        tableList = new ListView<>(sortedTables);
        // ---

        tableList.setCellFactory(_ -> {
            ListCell<TableData> cell = new ListCell<>();
            cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().map(TableData::name));
            return cell;
        });

        TextField nameField = new TextField();
        nameField.setOnAction(_ -> {
            if ( ! nameField.getText().isBlank()) {
                tables.add(new TableData(nameField.getText(), ""));
                nameField.clear();
            }
        });
        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");
        removeButton.disableProperty().bind(tableList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        removeButton.setOnAction(_ -> {
            TableData currentData = tableList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            // Code copied from original post:
            tables.remove(currentData);
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tableList);
        HBox controls = new HBox(5, nameField, removeButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setBottom(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

As you can see, adding tables works fine and they are always sorted by name:

and removing tables also works just fine:


I've checked this code, and it works just fine.  I'm going to try restarting my gui code from scratch with a working ListView.  I appreciate your help.
Someone else was asking for a minimum reproducible example.  I think that instead I'm going to start with something similar to your code and build onto until it breaks.  Then I'll just unbreak it.
I see several things in your code that are much more clear in your code.  The problem with my code may be some oddball thing that isn't obvious.

@StevenFletcher "I think that instead I'm going to start with something similar to your code and build onto until it breaks." Note that is typically how you should create a [mre].

Basically the problem is that SortedList superclass, AbstractList, implements method remove by throwing UnsupportedOperationException while the list returned by FXCollections.observableArrayList() correctly implements method remove, i.e. it removes the element from the list.
You just need to explore the source code of the class hierarchies for both SortedList and FXCollections.

But the code posted is not calling remove on the SortedList: it is calling it on the underlying list returned from FXCollections.observableArrayList(). That will actually work without throwing the exception.
